# GRPC Services: Central Proto Repository or Distributed

Tags: grpc, api-design

We plan to keep a central proto repository to keep all proto definitions and its generated code here. We would keep `messages` as well as `service` definitions in a central Git repo. We plan to drive API design standard from this central repository.

But, any service which want to use this to expose a sever service or generate clients would have to import from this repo (.pg.go).
Do you see any issue with this approach? Or do you see keeping service proto files individually in the service repos as a better alternative.

PS: Starter in the GRPC journey of building microservices. Still learning the right way to structure and distribute code here.

Answer (score 1):

This question occurs regularly and I suspect the fact that there's no published guidance is because the answer depends on your needs more than the technology's.

The specific issue of many vs one is not dissimilar to whether you prefer to use a monorepo and only you can effectively determine that. Perhaps one way to determine this is to understand now (and in the future) how many shared dependencies your services will have? Another may be to determine how many repos you'll have (how complex would it be to manage 10s or 100s of repos?).

In my experience, it's a good practice to keep the protos distinct (i.e. separate repo) from code that uses them. Not only may you want to version protos independently from implementations (across languages) but the implementations themselves are independent; in one use-case I must clone a repo containing an entire system (written mostly in one language) in order to get its protos to generate bindings in another language. In this case, it would be preferable if the repo were limited to just the protos.

You could look to examples for guidance. The gRPC repo keeps a bunch of stuff rooted on the [`grpc`](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/tree/master/src/proto/grpc) package in addition to [`math`](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/tree/master/src/proto/math). Although less broad, Google bundles its well-known types under [`google.protobuf`](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/tree/master/src/google/protobuf).

Comment: Thanks. Actually now I am also convinced, starting as a central repo is a good way to go. "You define what your service does as proto files in a central place and you abide by that contract." Also distributing proto files is hard, you need to copy them around.

Comment: You're welcome! This is just my perspective of course but I'm reasonable familiar with protos (as a user of others' and a developer of my own) and I've summarized my experience.